# How to receive a data from the JSon method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a method in my controller that submits some changes in the database after receiving a filename that being uploaded to the server. Also this method is getting the `fileNameOrigin` and `fileNameUnique` (to be downloaded for saving in the server folder)

```
 public JsonResult Upload()
        {
var upload = Request.Files[file];
string fileNameOrigin = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName);
string fileNameUnique = String.Format("{0}_" + fileNameOrigin,
                        DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
//there is more code that isn't needed in my case
return Json(fileNameOrigin, fileNameUnique);
        }
```

So, here's the question - how to send and receive this data on the client side?

```
$('#uploadFile').on('change', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var files = document.getElementById('uploadFile').files;            
            if (files.length > 0) {
                if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
                    var data = new FormData();
                    for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
                        data.append("file" + x, files[x]);

                    }

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("Upload", "ChatRooms")',
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        data: data,
                        success: onSuccess, //here I need to receive data and do smth with it
                        error: onError


                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: where is your onSuccess function ?

Comment: @FilipKováč
in the same file with above function. onSuccess just alerts user, that file has been uploaded successfully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a anonymous object with the properties that are required and then pass that single object to the `JSON` method like:

```
var data = new { 
                  FileNameOrigin = fileNameOrigin, 
                  FileNameUnique = fileNameUnique
               };

return Json(data);
```

In success callback of ajax, you can access it, for just to check it is working log it on console to see what server has returned like:

```
success: function(data) {

       console.log(data);
      },
```

you might also need to specify `datatype` in ajax call to `json` which dictates that JSON is expected from server to be returned in response to this ajax call:

```
dataType: "json"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: well, okay. And how do i receive this data on the client side? How to use it?

Comment: @LabLab in onSuccess(data) you have access to data from request as normal object for example data.fileNameOrigion. Try to console.log(data) where you can find the parametres of that object

Comment: @FilipKováč
wow, didn't suppose it could be so easy! thnx, i'll try this

Comment: doesn't work (took it from the browser inspector)
`function onSuccess(data) {
            var fileNameOrigin = data.fileNameOrigin; fileNameOrigin = undefined
            var fileNameUnique = data.fileNameUnique; fileNameUnique = undefined
            Materialize.toast('File uploaded '+ fileNameOrigin, 3000);

        };`

Comment: use `console.log(data);` to see what server returned, are you sure success is called?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, of course it called, I was just setting the breakpoints and then uploaded the file to check if something changed, but this variables are undefined. console log shows that data has an empty FormData()
looks like its referring to that `data` which was initialized here `if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
                    var data = new FormData();`

Comment: have your tried renaming the success parameter to something else, for example `response`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Yes, but it still not working, in that case parameter data is undefined, feels like the method which once send post request can't receive data